# Not able to use for loop using bash in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Following is my code

```
      def jsonObj;
      jsonObj = readJSON file: 'vars.json'

                sh "gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${jsonObj.cluster_name} --zone ${jsonObj.zone} --project ${jsonObj.project}"
                sh "echo ${jsonObj.ns}"         
                sh "kubectl get nodes"
                sh "for i in ${jsonObj.ns}; do kubectl create namespace \$i; done"
```

The variable file 'vars.json' is as shown below

```
        "ns": ["dev","qa","sbx"]
```

But when I execute my pipeline , the values from the variable are extracted with the other characters because of which the subsequent operation is failing

```
     + echo '[dev,' qa, 'sbx]'
     [dev, qa, sbx]
     + for i in '[dev,' qa, 'sbx]'
     + kubectl create namespace '[dev,'
     The Namespace "[dev," is invalid: .
```

Any suggestions to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Seems like sh in jenkins execute a set of bash commands, separated by semicolumns. Try using different quotations marks, `'` or `\`` for encapsulating everything inside a single command. Also, can you post the result of `sh "echo ${jsonObj.ns}"`?

Comment: Updated original description with the output of sh "echo ${jsonObj.ns}"

Comment: As you can see from the trace, the variable `jsonObj.ns` contains the **string** `[dev, qa, sbx]`. The word splitting in the for-loop sets the variable `i` successively to the pieces of this string, i.e. `[dev,` and `qa,` and `sbx]`. You would need `dev` an `qa` and `sbx` instead. BTW, are you sure that the Jenkins `sh` command actually runs a _bash_  and not a _sh_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `jsonObj` is a `Map` type in Groovy with a `List` type at the `ns` key, and your expectation is that when you implicitly cast this to a string during interpolation, then it will become iterable in the shell interpreter as well. Groovy types and shell interpreter type constructors are not syntactically isomorphic. You would want to use a Groovy iterator for the Groovy variable instead:

```
Map jsonObj = readJSON file: 'vars.json'
jsonObj.ns.each() { namespace ->
  sh(label: 'Create Kubernetes Namespace', script: "kubectl create namespace ${namespace}")
}
```

and then the shell interpreter command will receive the already resolved namespace variable from the pipeline correctly.